# Problems installing PyQt4 on Lion (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, installation, osx-lion, pyqt4

I'm trying to install the python IDE [eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) on a mac with Lion. I have installed PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.6, QT-1.1.4  and SIP-4.13. When I navigate to the folder where I downloaded `eric4` and run the command `sudo python install.py` I get the following message:

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 2.7.1
Found PyQt4
Sorry, please install QtHelp.
Error: No module named QtHelp
```

How can I install the QtHelp module? I used the QT installer with the default options. When I went to reinstall it using the custom options, I could not see the help files listed anywhere.

---

EDIT:

In retrospect, I realize this has nothing to do with Eric, but rather my inability to install PyQT4.
When I run the line:

```
python2.7 configure.py -w -g -q /Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/qmake
```

I get the following output:

```
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
g++ -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I. -I/Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I/Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/QtHelp.framework/Headers -I/Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -pipe -O2 -w cfgtest_QtHelp.cpp -o cfgtest_QtHelp -F/Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/Users/cel/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -headerpad_max_install_names -framework QtHelp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccPUS9BG.o
  "QString::free(QString::Data*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccPUS9BG.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Perhaps this is due to a problem compiling this version of PyQT4 on `Lion`?

Comment: What versions of pyqt, sip and eric are you using?

Comment: @ekhumoro I just updated my question.

Comment: What's the precise version of PyQt4? Did you compile everything (other than Qt) yourself?

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm using PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.6. Yes, I compiled everything myself other than Qt.

Comment: It looks like [Qt does not officially support Lion](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/developing-on-mac.html), but that doesn't necessarily mean it can't be done. This will probably make no difference, but try adding `--use-arch x86_64` to your `configure` command. If that doesn't change anything, I would suggest you try asking on the [PyQt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) (and make sure you include the full, verbose output from the configure script in your post).

Comment: I tried use `--use-arch x86_64` but a message underneath appeared `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. Thanks for your help, @ekhumoro

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check whether the `QtHelp` module is, in fact, installed.

Run this command in a console to find the location of the PyQt4 package:

```
python2.7 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

Look inside the resulting directory for any `PyQt4/QtHelp.*` files. If there's nothing there, run the configuration for PyQt4 again with the `verbose` flag:

```
$ make clean
$ python2.7 configure.py -w
```

This should give some error messages indicating why the configuration for the `QtHelp` module failed. This would most likely be because some required libraries or build tools are missing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; `QtHelp` is not there. I saw a message appear stating `this version of PyQT4 was not supported for the current OS` but no errors appeared. However it seems to have prevented the installation of `QtHelp`.

Comment: @celenius. Are you sure you're using the [right source code](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)? Also, when you run `configure.py -w`, just after confirming the licence, there should be a line `Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...`. What comes after that?

Comment: hmmm, I used this `PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8.6.tar.gz` which I assumed was the correct version, even though I'm using `Lion`. I just added in the message I got after `Checking to see if the QtHelp....` to my question; the problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

I found sth on mail list, and work fine for me:)

> I had to patch the configure script with this line so the qthelp
>   module loads the qtcore libraries when building.
>
> --- PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9/configure.py~      2011-12-23 14:53:07.981490550
>   +0100
>   +++ PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9/configure.py       2011-12-23 14:52:38.384984221
>   +0100
>   @@ -1264,7 +1264,7 @@
>       opengl = (mname == "QtOpenGL")
>
> ```
> qt = [mname]
> ```
>
> -    if mname in ("QtOpenGL", "QtWebKit"):
>   +    if mname in ("QtHelp", "QtOpenGL", "QtWebKit"):
>           qt.append("QtCore")
>
> ```
> makefile = sipconfig.ProgramMakefile(sipcfg, console=1, qt=qt,
> warnings=0,
> ```

Works fine for me.